# Optimize sql query execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to optimize queries for views,

Below is one of query used in views:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> 
WHERE (2=(SELECT value FROM dbo.version WHERE a=<somevalue>))
```

Although its showing number of execution as 0,but it is giving cost as 19% on scanning `<tablename>`

How to optimize its execution plan?

If I run the query like below, it is giving 0% as cost

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE (2=(1))
```

Here is the view :

```
CREATE   VIEW v1
AS
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (1=(SELECT value FROM config WHERE year=2019))
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE (2=(SELECT value  FROM config WHERE year=2019))
GO
```

Currently both t1 and t2 are coming in actual execution plan,but i want 2nd select not to be evaluated if ist select is true and vice versa

Comment: Please pick ONE database platform to tag with

Comment: Well, of course the cost would be less... it's a literal which will always be FALSE versus a sub-query with a predicate that may or may not have an index it can use. Post the actual execution plan if this is sql server: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ I removed Oracle tag since everything else pointed to SQL Server... but you still need to pick a version. Also, your question is very vague and unclear. We need a real, reproducable problem. There's dozens of reasons why your view could be slow.

Comment: I need to optmize plan in such a way that the query should check where clause first and do not go inside the table.Updated query in the question

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to re-write it like this, depending on the contents of `version`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM <tablename> t
INNER JOIN dbo.version v ON v.value = 2 AND a=<somevalue>
```

If that causes duplicates in the result set, an APPLY might help. However, I don't have a good sense yet for whether the query optimizer will do any better:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM <tablename> t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 v.value FROM dbo.version v WHERE v.value = 2 AND a=<somevalue>) z
```

You might also need to adjust that depending on what you mean with the column `a`.

Comment: Hey Joel,Thanks,I tried these but still cost is showing in execution plan on table t,ideally it should not go to the table,if where condition is not evaluating to true